# UseState Hooks in react gatsby

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import Layout from "../components/layout"

const blog = () => {
    const [state, setState] = useState({
        name: 'Kerry',
        age: 20
    });
    return (
        <Layout>
        <div>
            <h1>blog</h1>
            <p>Post will show up here later on</p>
            {state.name + state.age}
            
        </div>
        </Layout>
    )
}

export default blog
```

Hi I am trying to print out name from state. I am using react hooks. This project is built in gatsby command.
From my understanding  the line  `{state.name + state.age}` should return my name and age.

but the programs terminal is returning **rebuilding failed**

Also The program is giving me 2 error.

here theses two

```
5:19  warning  'setState' is assigned a value but never used no-unused-vars

 5:31  error    React Hook "useState" is called in function "blog" which is neither a React function component or a custom React Hook function  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks
```

So a, i using useState wrong

Comment: React components must be Uppercase. Change "blog" to "Blog".

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#:~:text=User%2DDefined%20Components%20Must%20Be,Foo%20%2F%3E%20compile%20to%20React.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Components **must** start with capital letters. You have to change `blog` to `Blog`. The rest of the code seems correct.

This is because if they start with a lowercase letter, it is interpreted as a built-in component such as `<p>` or `<img>` by React. Since they are passed to `React.createElement` it breaks your code.

You can check for further information in [React's official documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#user-defined-components-must-be-capitalized).